# Does AWS SDK for Java communicate in a secure channel with S3 servers?

Tags: java, security, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I would like to think that it's a big YES, but I prefer to ask before to suppose. So, do you know if the AWS SDK for Java always uses a secure channel when I download/upload files from/to S3 buckets? Or this is something that should be configured when I write the code or into the S3 buckets itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon S3 end points support both HTTP and HTTPS (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)

when you're using the Java SDK you will create an `AmazonS3Client` and if you do not specify to he specifically using the HTTP protocol it will use by default HTTPS (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#setEndpoint(java.lang.String))

> Callers can pass in just the endpoint (ex: "ec2.amazonaws.com") or a
>   full URL, including the protocol (ex: "https://ec2.amazonaws.com"). If
>   the protocol is not specified here, the default protocol from this
>   client's ClientConfiguration will be used, **which by default is HTTPS**.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Also, the [setRegion()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#setRegion-com.amazonaws.regions.Region-) method that's used in the [AWS SDK sample project](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/java/), which is an alternative to setEndpoint(), also uses https by default.

Answer (score 2):

Answer with link to a newer [Java SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setProtocol-com.amazonaws.Protocol-):

> setProtocol - The default configuration is to use **HTTPS for all requests** for increased security.