# Does AWS SDK for .NET communicate in a secure channel with S3 servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

Does anyone know if the AWS SDK for .NET always uses a secure channel when I download/upload files from/to S3 buckets? Or this is something that should be configured when I write the code or into the S3 buckets itself?

The question is similar to one here for java

[Does AWS SDK for Java communicate in a secure channel with S3 servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773123/does-aws-sdk-for-java-communicate-in-a-secure-channel-with-s3-servers)

The answers for this question seem to be out of date as the methods they recommend as secure are deprecated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, https is default, unless you specify differently. From [.NET AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Config_CommunicationProtocol.htm)

> Gets and Sets the property that determines whether the HTTP or HTTPS protocol is used to make requests to the S3 service. **By default Protocol.HTTPS is used to communicate with S3**.